# Unity2D predictive bow aiming using object array only displaying vertically

Tags: unity, c#

I am making a bow and arrow game in Unity2D, and I want to use an Angry Birds style predictive aiming system(like in this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6Jqy.png).

I have loosely followed a tutorial, but for whatever reason, in my game, it only predicts on the vertical axis. The code works by initializing GameObjects and placing them in a list. Here is the code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Points.Length; i++){
                Points[i].transform.position = PointPosition(i * time);          
            }
```

```
Vector2 PointPosition(float t){
        Vector2 currentPointPos = (Vector2)transform.position + ((direction.normalized * force * t) * 0.5f * Physics2D.gravity * (t*t));
        return currentPointPos;
    }
```

The way I understood it, by using the `+` operand on `transform.position` it would add to both axis'. Am I wrong about this? Do I need to do two operations for both axis'? Or is my error somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your formula:

```
Vector2 currentPointPos = (Vector2)transform.position 
     + ((direction.normalized * force * t) 
     * 0.5f * Physics2D.gravity * (t*t));
```

Should be:

```
Vector2 currentPointPos = (Vector2)transform.position 
     + ((direction.normalized * arrowSpeed * t) 
     + 0.5f * Physics2D.gravity * (t*t));
```

The gravity term should be added, not multiplied.

Also, the coefficient on the aiming direction is a speed (so that together they make a velocity), not a force. Using a force value in this place will not give you a correct prediction.

[You can slightly improve this prediction by adding half a physics timestep's worth of acceleration to the velocity term](https://twitter.com/D_M_Gregory/status/996376144357179393).